# If an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is diagonalizable and has only one eigenvalue $\lambda$ with multiplicity $n$, then $A = \lambda I$. True or False?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Like the title says, "If an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is diagonalizable and has only one eigenvalue $\lambda$ with multiplicity $n$, then $A = \lambda I$. True or False?"

My gut is telling me that this is true, but I'm having a little difficulty proving it formally. There's probably a very obvious proof, but thus far it has alluded me.

In any case, this is what I've done:

Since $A$ is diagonalizable, there exists a factorization such that $A = S^{-1}\Lambda S$. Since we know the eigenvalues are $\lambda$ with multiplicity $n$, $\Lambda = \text{diag}(\lambda, \lambda, ...)$.

If I'm given $A = \lambda I$, it's easy to show $\lambda I = S^{-1}\Lambda S$ where $S = I$ and $\Lambda = \text{diag}(\lambda, \lambda, ...)$. (Having normalized the eigenvectors). The trouble I'm having is showing $A = \lambda I$ under the given conditions.

I can simply let $S = \lambda I$, and thus $A = \lambda I$, but something about this approach feels off. (This is just my line of thought right now).

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: The LaTeX command for "times" is \times, which yields $\times$.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to use that instead.

Comment: A square matrix is diagonizable if and only if it's minimal polynomial is a product of distinct monic lineair factors. What does this give in your case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have it! Since $A$ is diagonalizable, there exist an invertible matrix $S$ such that $\Lambda=\lambda I = S^{-1}AS$, so $A=S\Lambda S^{-1} = \lambda S^{-1}S = \lambda I$.

Answer (score 1):

If $V^{-1}A V = \Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal, then the eigenvalues of $A$ and  $\Lambda$ are the same, hence $\Lambda = \lambda I$. Premultiplying by $V$ and post multiplying by $V^{-1}$ yields $A = \lambda I$.

Answer (score 1):

As $A$ is diagonalisable, there is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix $Q$ such that $Q^{-1}AQ$ is diagonal; in particular, the diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of $A$. So we have $Q^{-1}AQ = \lambda I$. What happens when you rearrange for $A$?